# How does adding IDisposable change the semantics of a class?

Tags: .net, idisposable

The MSDN documentation for [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) states that:

> It is a version-breaking change to add the `IDisposable` interface to an existing class, because it changes the semantics of the class.

*What **exactly** does this mean?*

I can see how *removing* `IDisposable` would be a big deal. Instantiating a class inside of a `using` statement would no longer be possible, for example.  But what else makes `IDisposable` special, especially in the context of *adding* the interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you implement `IDisposable`, you're basically adding semantics of "you should dispose this when you're done with it". That means that existing code which *doesn't* dispose of it is violating that implicit contract... so there's no way of going from "not implementing `IDisposable`" to "implementing `IDisposable`" while keeping clients using your type correctly, unless you also have access to all that client code.

To give another example - suppose the documentation for `GetHashCode` was updated to say "This should always return an even number" - that would be a breaking change because existing code could easily return an odd number. Again, it wouldn't break in *source code* - everything would still build - but you'd be changing the contract to make it more restrictive.

If you view the implementation of `IDisposable` as a contract on the *client* code, hopefully it's clearer why it's a breaking change.

Comment: Ah, of course. Yep, you're causing the client code to be no longer using the class correctly. For some reason I was thinking this changed some sort of under-the-hood compiler-ism (like `using`, for example).  Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `IDisposable` tells clients that they always need to dispose the class.

That is a breaking change.

Comment: Yep, it's obvious now :-) This "breaks" clients that were never coded to `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 1):

If a class does not implement `IDisposable`, code which uses the class will likely create and abandon instances without examining them to see if they implement `IDisposable`.  Even if a later version of the class does implement `IDisposable`, that change will not magically cause code which never checks for `IDisposable` to magically start calling `IDisposable.Dispose`; client code which explicitly checks for `IDisposable` and attempts to call `Dispose` if possible (e.g. the compiler-generated code associated with `foreach` blocks) will start calling `IDisposable.Dispose` once that becomes possible, but most code won't bother.

Note that not all of the code which uses an object will have to worry about its implementing `IDisposable`.  The only time something should call `IDisposable` on an object is if it is the last thing to hold a "useful" reference to it.  If code gives a method a reference to an object and the method won't do anything with the object after it returns, the caller will easily be able to know when the method is done with the object, and so the caller will just as able to call `Dispose` as would be the method.  Consequently, there would be no reason for the method to call Dispose.  On the other hand, if code calls an object's implementation of `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` and that method needs the services of an object that will require cleanup once enumeration is complete, the only way the object which implemented `GetEnumerator` could possibly when the services are no longer required will be if the code that called `GetEnumerator` calls `Dispose` on the returned enumerator once it is no longer required.

Incidentally, whether it's necessary to call `IDisposable.Dispose` on the object returned by a factory method like `GetEnumerator` doesn't necessarily depend on the factory method's return type.  If one calls the non-generic `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` on an object, semantic correctness requires that one check whether the returned object instance implements `IDisposable` (it might do so, even though the declared type of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` does not) and call `Dispose` on it if so.  From that standpoint, having a later version of an abstract base class implement `IDisposable` when earlier versions didn't do so might not really be a breaking change.  If code which called factory methods returning the abstract class were required to call `Disposed` on the returned items whenever it was possible to do so, having the base class implement `IDisposable` would not add any new responsibilities to the client code--it would merely make it easier for client code to actually care out the responsibilities it was going to have anyway (checking whether an object instance implements `IDisposable` is slower and more cumbersome than would be calling `IDisposable.Dispose` unconditionally on a class which implements it as a do-nothing method).